# Why does not "await" work in async method?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await

Why does not "await" work?

```
Future<void> f1() async{
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2), (){
    print('f1');
  });
}

void main() async{
  print('start');
  await f1();
  print('end');
}
```

output

```
start
end
f1
```

but `await` working in next code.

```
Future<void> f1() async{
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2), (){
    print('f1');
  });
}

void main() async{
  print('start');
  await f1();
  print('end');
}
```

output

```
start
f1
end
```

why????

I dont understand.....

Answer (score 2):

Because in the first code block `f1()` is awaited and it's child `Future` is not. In the second it's returned. If you want to wait for the delayed `Future`, `await` it as well. Like so

```dart
Future<void> f1() async{
 await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2), (){
    print('f1');
  });
}

void main() async{
  print('start');
  await f1();
  print('end');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

because the in the first one, you only interupt for the `f1`,

to make you better understanding see this

```
Future<void> f1() async{
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2), (){
    print('f1');
  });
  print("---done---");
}

void main() async{
  print('start');
  await f1();
  print('end');
}
```

result:

```
start
---done---
end
f1
```

---

> the `f1` has been done executed, the `Future.delayed` has been on the
> queue, but since its not use `await` then its not interupt the proces.
> the next one `print('end')` will be executed.

---

but if you also add `await` inside the `f1` , it will interupt the process

```
Future<void> f1() async{
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2), (){
    print('f1');
  });
  print("---done---");
}
```

result:

```
start
f1
---done---
end
```

in the second one, since you are returning the `Future.delayed` which mean, it direclty execute the `Future.delayed` and interupt the process.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either `await Future.delayed` or `return Future.delayed`. The `f1` call in the `main` expects a `Future` object to be returned which it can await.